# Copying Windows files from exFAT to HFS+

Tags: hfs+, exfat

I have an archive (roughly 1TB) of Windows & DOS files: essentially installation files from a lot of software and then a lot of personal documents (doc, pdf, excel, etc) that I had stored for a long time on an exFAT drive. I'm thinking of moving everything to a HFS+ drive (as I don't use a PC much, if I need to use a PC I can always copy them back to exFAT to access them), 2 questions:

1. Is this fundamentally a good idea? I know that the 2 file systems are different and potentially some Windows filenames might not work on HFS+. Are there other incompartibility issues? I went through most of the files on exFAT and there are no hidden or other files still...
2. If I copy them is there a way to confirm what has been copied accurately and what not?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It won't by this point makes any major difference. ExFAT cannot carry 'extra' data or any permissions structure, MS terms some of this data as *streams* & would have already complained as you initially moved anything containing such streams as you initiated the original copy to ExFAT.

Because of this, there's nothing 'extra' to preserve, so the copy is not going to make any noticeable changes.

The HD internal firmware & the OS itself will manage the integrity of any copy process, so as you copy to HFS, you can rely on these to make sure this integrity is preserved [there could potentially be  an issue if data on the drive was *already* corrupted, but you're past this point anyway]. Windows installers are 'flat files' unlike Mac apps which are really folders, so there's nothing to lose in copying them too.

As regards file names, Windows has far more restrictions than Mac. You are probably already safe. Worry if you find one.